# How to automate a django functions when a certain condition is met by a django model's field

Tags: python, django

My problem is, how do I make a Django function run automatically when a certain condition is met by a Django model field. Google decided not to be collaborative on this. Say for example, I have the following model:

```
class Check(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    interval = models.DurationField(default=td(hours=1))
    last_run = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def run_function(self):
        return HttpResponse("....")
```

I have a model named Check which has fields for name, the intervals which I expect a function to be run and the last time the function was run. I need to call the function each time after the specific interval. What is the simplest way to write a function that will be called or will call another function after the interval passes?

I am currently learning Django and I got stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want periodic task to be run under Django you can give a look to http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works, though a bit of an overkill for a small project. Is there a library that doesn't need a broker?

Comment: You could try redis. Installing redis-queue and then this library https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler and scheduling from Django into redis.